# postgres rename database not working

Tags: postgresql

```
bin]# ./createdb cx123 -U postgres
[bin]# ./createdb cx111 -U postgres

[bin]# ./psql -d cx123 -U postgres Welcome to psql 8.3.7, the PostgreSQL interactive terminal.

Type: \copyright for distribution terms \h for help with SQL commands \? for help with psql commands \g or terminate with semicolon to execute query \q to quit

cx123=# ALTER DATABASE cx111 RENAME TO cx222
cx123-# \q

[bin]# ./psql -l -U postgres
List of databases
Name  | Owner    | Encoding
-----------+----------+---------- 
cx111 | postgres | UTF8
cx123 | postgres | UTF8
(2 rows)
###################################################
```

Hi guys, See the above code, I failed to rename cx111 to cx 222, any idea? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

You need to terminate the ALTER statement with a semicolon.

The way you typed it, it never got executed because psql was waiting for the statement to be finished.